# Cookie::get returns null, laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, cookies, null

I'm trying to cookie user login values, 
I grouped in route like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {

  Route::post('/admin/addArticle', [
      'as' => 'article_save', 'uses' => 'AdminController@saveCover'
  ]);

  Route::get('/admin/introduction', [
      'as' => 'introduction', 'uses' => 'AdminController@introduction'
  ]);

});
```

AdminController:

```
$cookie = Cookie::forever('admin', $admin);

Cookie::queue($cookie);

return Redirect::route('introduction')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Models/Admin:

```
if (Cookie::has('admin')) {

     //echo 'admin is not in session but cookie';
     $admin = Cookie::get('admin');
     //...
```

but it's not go in this if never and nothing is saved in cookie !!!
Unfortunately I have upgraded to laravel 5.4 of 5.2 and anything is in the wrong way now :((((
please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel is encrypting cookies, so I had to add an exception for them in `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies\`:

```
protected $except = [
    'cookie_name'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change  the way you set the cookie to `Cookie::queue('admin', $admin);`

Comment: thx for ur answer, i changed it and 
Cookie::hasQueued('admin')  returns true in controllers method and fals in Models/admin

Comment: You should check if the cookie exists with this : `(Cookie::get('cookiename') !== null)`